# Update attributes separately in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, update-attributes

Trying to update 2 attributes to a User model, this is my current code in the Users controller:

```
def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(songkickID: params[:user][:songkickID], jamID: params[:user][:jamID])

  redirect_to @user
else
  redirect_to @user
end
end
```

The Songkick ID and the Jam ID are entered into 2 different fields. However, with the current code, if I attempt to update the Jam ID on its own, it updates that attribute, but then redirects to the user page (as expected), where the Songkick ID is now nil. Upon entering the Songkick ID again, the Jam ID becomes nil. I suppose this is because they are both part of the same if statement in the controller?

I attempted to use an elsif for the jamID params, but it does not seem to recognise at all (i.e. won't update that attribute for the user). Also attempted || conditional operator.

EDIT: Here's the 2 different forms:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :jamID, :id=>"jamURL" %>


    <%= f.submit "Jam ID", :onclick => "changeImg()", id: "saveJam" %>

<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :songkickID %>

  <%= f.submit "Songkick ID", :type => :image, :src => image_path("songkicklogo.png"), id: "skLogo" %>
<% end %>
```

And I tried modifiying the code to update_column, but I get wrong number of arguments (1 for 2).

EDIT 2: Following layout from Hartl's Rails Tutorial, I attempted this to define strong parameters:

```
private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:songkickID, :jamID)
end
```

But I still get the Forbidden Attributes Error?

EDIT 3: The following code passes, but I worry it doesn't adhere to Rails 4 strong parameters:

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end



def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:songkickID, :jamID)
end

def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

  redirect_to @user
else
  redirect_to @user
end


end
end
```

If I move update to below the update method, I get an undefined variable/method error for user_params, and I cannot make it private.

Comment: I think I don't fully understand what you're asking. Do you want both attributes to be updated? Can you show us the form which sets these values?

Comment: Is there any reason for you to create two different forms? Because if you want to update both attributes at once they should be in the same

Comment: Two different forms because I don't want them updated at the same time (songkick ID is a one time thing, Jam ID will be updated frequently).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So - why are you explicitly naming the attributes in your update_attributes?

You should be able to use the following:

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
```

Remember that if you've named your form fields correctly,  params[:user] is a hash that will already have the keys you want (:songkickID etc)

Now - you will get one of two things coming through to your action, which you then pass through to update_attributes as:

```
{:songkickID => someID}
{:jamID => someOtherID}
```

which will correctly update your user and only change the one that is passed.

The problem with your earlier code was that what you passed to update attribute was:

```
{:songkickID => someID, :jamID => nil}
{:songkickID => nil, :jamID => someOtherID}
```

which was deliberately overwriting the other id with the nil you passed.

EDIT from OP: Thanks for this, and here's my final controller code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end


def update
@user = User.find(params[:id])
if @user.update_attributes(user_params)

  redirect_to @user
else
  redirect_to @user
end   
end


private


def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:songkickID, :jamID)
end
end
```

Comment: Per your earlier comment, here's the 2 different forms:

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :jamID, :id=>"jamURL" %>
      
       
        <%= f.submit "Jam ID", :onclick => "changeImg()", id: "saveJam" %>

<% end %>

and

<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.text_field :songkickID %>

      <%= f.submit "Songkick ID", :type => :image, :src => image_path("songkicklogo.png"), id: "skLogo" %>
    <% end %>

<br />

And I tried modifiying the code to update_column, but I get wrong number of arguments (1 for 2).

Comment: This doesn't work well in a comment - can you put that into your question so it can be formatted

Comment: Right - so I see wha you mean about the individual fields.
So my code above should work - because it means you're not literally passing a nil for the *other* field (that you're not updating). The code above will only pass the field that is being changed.

Comment: Right now I'm getting a Forbidden Attributes error, is this because of strong parameters? Same when trying Carl's suggested answer.

Comment: Are you using Rails 4? In which case, you also need to update the require/permit section down the bottom of the controller...
If you're using Rails 3 - do you have attr_protected or attr_accessible?

Comment: Rails 4, still trying to get the hang of strong parameters, attr_accessible would make things much easier... So I guess I need to def user_params in a private section in the controller?

Comment: When I define user_params at the bottom of the controller, I get an undefined local variable/method error, whereas if I move it above update, the code passes. Is there a way to get it to work at the bottom in the private section?

Comment: @user2445163 If you can't solve this error you could use my answer. Although this one is much cleaner

Comment: Hmmm.. not sure why moving it about the file should make a difference - I suspect there may have been a copy-paste error...

Comment: You're totally right, forgot pasted it one "end" too soon, will update answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In last case scenario:

```
    def update
      if params[:user][:songkickID]
        received_param = { songkickID: params[:user][:songkickID] }
      elsif params[:user][:jamID]
        received_param = { jamID: params[:user][:jamID] }
      end

      @user.update_attributes(received_param)
      redirect_to @user
    end
```

Note: I removed the last condition since it wasn't useful

Comment: Got a syntax error with this one, just went with the code I updated in Taryn's answer, thanks anyway.

Comment: @Rafael - that works, but again - it's a bit cumbersome and not necessary in this instance.  Due to the way the OP set up the forms - params[:user] works too.